# VerificationTest for uncaught `Throw`?

Tags: testing-and-verification

I want to demonstrate that `Catch[x_]` does not catch things thrown with a tag.

```
Catch[Throw[0, 0]]
```

gives

> Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[0,0] returned to top level.
>
> Hold[Throw[0, 0]]

But I cannot put this behaviour into a `VerificationTest` that results in Success.
I tried

```
VerificationTest[Catch[Throw[0, 0]], 
 Hold[Throw[0, 0]], {Throw::nocatch}, {}]
```

but this gives an Error TestResultObject.

Usually, using the third argument is the way to go with messages:

```
VerificationTest[Message[a::b], Null, {a::b}]
```

I guess I could use something like `` GeneralUtilities`CatchAll `` to construct the test manually, but I was under the impression that `VerificationTest` catches all Error conditions.

Any ideas?

---

I also seems to require manual work to catch `Abort[]`.

```
VerificationTest[Abort[], $Aborted]
```

gives an Error-result too, but the Abort is shielded from the rest of the execution:

```
VerificationTest[Abort[], $Aborted]*2
```

does not give `$Aborted` like `Abort[]*2` does.

Comment: It was hard to follow that post for me. Could you maybe add a scrrenshot or two? p.s. what about `Catch[  Catch[Throw[0, 0]];,  _] =!= Null`

Answer (score 2):

On a rare occasion, something produces an uncaught `Throw` that must be tested for, and as you have noticed, checking for the message is insufficient. So, if I know the form, e.g. `Throw[0, 0]`, I wrap the expression in another `Catch`, and then use the outer `Catch` to return the test result, e.g.

```
VerificationTest[
 Catch[  Catch[Throw[0, 0]]; (* or some other expression *)
   True, (* No uncaught Throw *)
   _, (* Catch all tagged Throws *)
   False&
 ]
]
```

The key is the last argument has to be a function, which normally would return

```
f[thrownValue, tag]
```

But, in this case we just want it to return `False` if the execution ever makes it to that branch.  For untagged `Throw`, we have to exercise some caution as `Catch[Throw[...]]` will return the value passed by `Throw`. So, the solution is to have `Catch` return a value that is not likely to be thrown, e.g.

```
VerificationTest[
 Catch[ (*throwing expression*); "Not Thrown"],
 "Not Thrown"
]
```

where `Catch` will produce `"Not Thrown"`, if no uncaught, untagged `Throw` is produced. These two forms can be combined if the form is not known, as follows

```
VerificationTest[
 Catch[ Catch[ expr; "Not Thrown"], _, "Tagged expr Thrown"&]
 ,
 "Not Thrown"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CheckAll` to "catch" all "uncaught" control flow statements. Then wrap those statements with special head to make sure that they were not returned by ordinary evaluation of expression.

```
ClearAll[stoppedControlFlow, confineControlFlow]
stoppedControlFlow // Attributes = HoldAll;
confineControlFlow = Function[,
    CheckAll[#, Function[, Replace[HoldComplete@##, {
        HoldComplete[_, Hold@ctrlFlow__] :> stoppedControlFlow@ctrlFlow,
        HoldComplete[result_, Hold[]] :> result
    }], HoldAllComplete]],
    HoldAllComplete
];
```

Now all following `VerificationTest`s are successful.

```
VerificationTest[2 + 3 // confineControlFlow, 5]
VerificationTest[Catch[Throw[0, 0]] // confineControlFlow, stoppedControlFlow@Throw[0, 0]]
VerificationTest[Abort[] // confineControlFlow, stoppedControlFlow@Abort[]]
VerificationTest[Goto[1] // confineControlFlow, stoppedControlFlow@Goto[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `VerificationTest` with Outcome `Error` cannot be fixed by changing the expected-messages argument. This only applies to `MessagesFailure` Outcome (orange versus yellow cross, a bit hard to distinguish).

Tests that result in `Error` must be fixed on a case-by-case basis: There could be an error in either of the expressions involved in the test or in some of the options (e.g. the SameTest not returning True or False).